# Unknown quantity of items in configuration files using ConfigParser

Tags: python, configuration-files, configparser

To be honest I'm writing this question to try to clear up my mind in the process. If I can't figure it out, I'll post it (which happened). I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on how to approach this problem. I'm still noob enough to get overwhelmed by this kind of problems.

Let's say that in certain section of my config file I want to give the user the flexibility to add an arbitrary quantity of items, e.g.:

```
[mysection]
item1 = value1
item2 = value2
item3 = value3
```

The items quantity can increase as the user wishes.

Which would be a nice way to parse this? At the moment I only came up with string manipulation by index of the list returned by ConfigParser's items method.

Hope I explained myself clear. Anyone has faced this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems to me that [`ConfigParser.items(section)`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser.items) offers the functionality you need.

---

Perhaps it would help to know that you can call `dict` on the resulting list of tuples? As in...

```
>>> l = [('name1', 'val1'), ('name2', 'val2')]
>>> d = dict(l)
>>> d
{'name2': 'val2', 'name1': 'val1'}
>>> d.items()
[('name2', 'val2'), ('name1', 'val1')]
>>> d.keys()
['name2', 'name1']
>>> d.values()
['val2', 'val1']
```

Comment: yeah, you mean iterate through list returned by ConfigParser.items(section) to find out how many items the user defined?

Comment: @jromero, ok, rereading your quesiton, it seems you already knew about the `items` method. So perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: no no, you understood it! The answer was on my right on my nose, you let me know it, right on the spot. You know, it's late and I'm tired, you've probably been there XD. Thanks so much!

Comment: @jromero, I have indeed been there. :)